# Delay displaying Active directory user in GDM

Tags: gdm, active-directory

After a lot of struggle, I have finally been able to make my laptop work not too bad with Active Directory/winbind authentication.

Anyway, I have an annoying issue that I can't figure out.
For the context, I am setting up a laptop, so it must be able to authenticate on the corporate network, and also outside of it.

Corporate network authentication works within acceptable time limits, but regarding the offline authentication I have important delays.
If the machine is totally disconnected from any network, meaning cable disconnected and wifi turned off, I have a consistent 1 minute 40 seconds delay before my AD account appears in GDM. The measure starting after I validated the disk encryption password, so I guess the GDM "loading time" should be 1m30s, hence 90s.
I do not know if that time limit can ring a bell.

In case, I am connected to a foreign network (i.e other than corporate, like home or guest network) then it is impossible for GDM to display my user.
My best guess here is that "it" (whatever "it" is) tries to contact the domain using the IPs that were provided in the krb5.conf file and that it cannot work.

So do you have any idea on how to change that timeout value for the detection of a usable DC, and to avoid those delays ?

Any lead would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.